# unable to install python package/module on windows (tried easy install as well as pip already)

Tags: pip, easy-install

I use Ipython Notebook and at times need to install new python packages like plotly, scikit etc. I have already tried using the most popular methods PIP and Easy Install to install the packages directly from cmd in windows but neither works. Here is the error that I get-

`C:\Users\xxxx>pip install plotly
Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"'`

And with easy install, I get some error as well.
Is there a third way of installing packages?
May be manually installing the package after downloading the .tar.gz file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. In case when both pip and easy_install fails, there is a third way (as simple as pip and easy_install).

Step 1) Go to https://pypi.python.org/ to find the desired python module/package and download the *.tar.gz file (example name: **plotly-1.9.6.tar.gz**) and save it anywhere.

Step 2) Unzip the file to get plotly-1.9.6. Inside this folder you will find **setup.py**. Open cmd and browse till the root folder of setup.py and use this command -

```
python setup.py install
```

And you are good.
If you know of any fourth method, do share it here.